# Abstract ASP.Net Identity 2.0 & Entity Framework From UI (MVC project)

Tags: design-patterns, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity, abstraction

So I assume some of you are familiar with the concept of the onion architecture discussed here http://www.develop.com/onionarchitecture and in other places.

Essentially, I am working towards building an MVC 5 solution using the repository pattern for all DB access and (by consequence of the Identity Entity Framework implementation) authorization.  When you build out a new MVC project Identity 2.0 an account controller is created using the EF implementation (effectively coupling your UI to EF and Identity references).  I want to remove all those references in favor of using a class library.

Currently, I have went with the approach of moving method calls one by one into an interface (that will be DI'd into the constructor of the account controller).  It is a slow and arduous process for anyone that has attempted it.  Is this the best approach to solve this problem?  I essentially want to get to a point in time where if Identity goes away or the developer wants to switch EF out in favor of nHibernate or another ORM that implementing a new concrete interface implementation/adjusting some DI code is all that is to it.

I have looked online and StackOverflow already and while some solutions/discussion has went on, no one seems to have a full solution that eliminates both EF and Identity from the MVC project.  Honestly I am beginning to wonder if it is worth the effort.  So any thought's/suggestions, has anyone pulled it off?

Comment: In fact Identity and EF are different things. And if you haven't used any EF specific staff in your controllers and middleware (if any). Changing the store to any other technique will change nothing in your code. Only some application level configuration stuff will be changed.

Comment: Yes I am aware EF (ORM) and Identity is a security implementation for ASP.NET, with a concrete EF implementation.  I think I found a way to accomplish my goal as I have successfully moved all Identity/EF specific items to a class library.  Now in theory I should be able to create a Repo to inject into my controller.

Comment: @Shawn what did you end up doing?  I too am looking to decouple EF from my MVC app

Comment: I've come to realize that the ef implementation is already pretty well abstracted.  I believe the mvc app has no ef dependency directly.  So you have a choice you can add an interface to another project and abstract out the ef implementation or treat it as a special case.  Ie if someone wants to switch to nhibernate for identity they just replace the using statement with an nhibernate implementation of identity.  Hope this helps it can be hard to get, I spent hours looking this over to reach this conclusion.